# Angular directive that doesn't match mailto

Tags: angular, css-selectors, angular-directive

I'm trying to write a directive selector that matches any anchor tag with an href that isn't a mailto.  I tried the following:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: 'a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"])',
    standalone: true
})
```

but it's still matching the mailto links.  How do I write it so that it doesn't match mailto?

Comment: `^=` doesnt really seem to be supported by [Angular directive selector](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector)

Comment: The only attribute comparator allowed is : "=". Selector of directives are not really css selector. You can see how angular parse it on : https://ydomenjoud.github.io/angular-selector-parser/ . Result are really weird, and leads to mistakes. Yours is parsed as a[href]:not(mailto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SurajRao mentioned that seems the`^=` symbol doesn't work in the Angular Directive selector, you may consider working with regex to check the `HtmlArchorElement` with the href starts with "mailto:".

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'a[href]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ExcludeMailToDirective {
  readonly regex = new RegExp(/^mailto:/);

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    if (!this.regex.test(el.nativeElement.href))
      el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  }
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2om4k?file=src/app/exclude-mail-to.directive.ts)